# Assets not loading in sails.js app

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, less, sails.js

I moved from Arch Linux to Windows 7.

I've installed nodejs, npm, sails, grunt. I created a new sails project with `sails new <name>` and started it with `sails lift`.

My assets will be not compiled or injected by sails. .tmp/public does not exist, too.

Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: Please put some more information for others to be able to suggest solutions

Comment: I don't know which infos does anyone need to help me. I have no errors or anything else, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this issue

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3013

Its probably that Grunt is defaulting to False, which means the grunt work flow is not building your assets or creating the public web folder.