# Sails is not injecting the files within the assets folder

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I just did a fresh installation of sails (v0.11.0) in my server and after checking this up and working on controllers I found that css, js and templates files included into the assets folders are not being injected to the layout, if there any reason for this to happen? I mean, it is a clean fresh sails installation....

Comment: Are the standard sails.js views showing ok? What does it do when you access http://localhost:1337?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assets not loading in sails.js app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825711/assets-not-loading-in-sails-js-app)

Answer (score 4):

In my quest to get SailsJS to auto-inject stylesheets into the layout file under views/layouts/layout.handlebars in my case, I've found out a couple things...

When you first create your sails app using:

`sails new APPNAME --template=handlebars --verbose`

note: link below explains above syntax...

[Using handlebars templates in Sails.js](http://blog.colouringcode.com/using-handlebars-templates-in-sails-js/)

1. Go to config > views.js
   It will say:

   `layout: 'layouts/layout.handlebars'`

   change to:

   `layout: 'layouts/layout',`
2. Go to tasks > config > sails-linker.js
   Because I'm in development mode right now I will Ctrl + f searching for:
   "devStyles"

   ```
   devStyles: {
       options: {
           startTag: '<!--STYLES-->',
           endTag: '<!--STYLES END-->',
           fileTmpl: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">',
           appRoot: '.tmp/public'
       },

       files: {
           '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').cssFilesToInject,
           'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').cssFilesToInject,
           'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').cssFilesToInject
           //ADD HANDLEBARS INJECTION HERE
       }
   },
   ```

Notice it has .html, & .ejs types being injected but not .handlebars

add this line:

`'views/**/*.handlebars': require('../pipeline').cssFilesToInject`

where I commented:

`//ADD HANDLEBARS INJECTION HERE`

At this point you should be able to drop a .css file into assets > styles and have it auto-copied to .tmp/public/styles

run:

`sails lift`

in your command prompt and give it about 20 seconds or so to have the stylesheet manifest its style on whatever page you have in your routes.js

```
    '/': {
      view: 'index'
    }
```

As you can see, I made a new .handlebars file index.handlebars and set it as my root level page.  You may have to refresh the page a time or two to get the newly auto-injected CSS to show.

P.S.  It appears there is no more need to append `--linker` when first creating a SailsJS project.  Also fyi, I'm using sails version 0.11.0

Also if you run `sails lift --verbose` the line below is how you know the .handlebars injection is working

`verbose: Grunt :: File "views/layouts/layout.handlebars" updated.`

Hope this helps!

Also, when adding Handlebars Helpers they should go in a file `helper.js` which should be located in config > helper.js

At the top of the `helper.js` file I found I had to require handlebars as follows

`handlebars = require('sails/node_modules/express-handlebars/node_modules/handlebars');`

Comment: Great! Thanks for this - might want to also say that there are a number of other objects in that same file that need updating in a similar way in order to get your scripts working, and to get things working in production etc.. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they fixed the `layouts/layout` part but not the sails-linker.js code.