# Sailsjs Socket.IO Uncaught TypeError: this.socket.request is not a function

Tags: backbone.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm following a tutorial on this site:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-data-in-sailsjs--net-31525

I'm stuck at the last part, leveraging web sockets.

Initially I typed the code but got the javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.socket.request is not a function
```

So I decided to copy and paste the tutorial's code but it gave the same error.

This is the code block:

```
var SailsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    sailsCollection: "",
    socket: null,
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        var where = {};
        if (options.where) {
            where = {
                where: options.where
            }
        }       
        if(typeof this.sailsCollection === "string" && this.sailsCollection !== "") {
            this.socket = io.connect();
            this.socket.on("connect", _.bind(function(){
                this.socket.request("/" + this.sailsCollection, where, _.bind(function(users){
                    this.set(users);
                }, this));

                this.socket.on("message", _.bind(function(msg){
                    var m = msg.uri.split("/").pop();
                    if (m === "create") {
                        this.add(msg.data);
                    } else if (m === "update") {
                        this.get(msg.data.id).set(msg.data);
                    } else if (m === "destroy") {
                        this.remove(this.get(msg.data.id));
                    }
                }, this));
            }, this));
        } else {
            console.log("Error: Cannot retrieve models because property 'sailsCollection' not set on the collection");
        }
    }
});
```

I believe the tutorial might be outdated, but I am still hopeful I can fix this last bit, especially coming all this way.

Anyone know the proper way to use Sailsjs socket in this BackboneJS code ? (I know I'm searching for a needle in a haystack here).

### Update 1:

Some initial discussion with the #Sailjs people on freenode IRC has brought to light the Grunt task are not running and so Socket.io is not being injected by Sails.js ?

### Update 2:

OK seems like a duplicate question has already been asked here:

[Sails is not injecting the files within the assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902593/sails-is-not-injecting-the-files-within-the-assets-folder)

Voting to close my own question, help me vote yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the `.sailsrc` in the project root, line:

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "hooks": {
    "grunt": true
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "hooks": {
  }
}
```